# Is there anyway to make conemu start as a bash terminal in some directory?

Tags: window, conemu

SI have Git installed in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` but I would like the conemu console to start in `C:\` but I can't seem to achieve this.

I went to tasks menu and created Git as the top task in the list and added parameters and login as `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i` but conemu always starts in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` dir with CMD session. I have to type `sh` or `bash` to start using bash (so I can ssh into my Vbox).

I have tried all the other tutorials, but I can't get it to work properly.

All i want is conemu to start as GIT as soon as I open it, and the default directory to change into `C:/`

Comment: [so] duplicate: [GIT Bash - how to default to other directory instead of home directory](//stackoverflow.com/q/7017143)

Answer (score 0):

You might try a fresh install of ConEmu. Once you've done that, you can add `cd ~` to your `.bashrc` or `.profile`.